# Getting a .jar error in startup of wso2server

Tags: java, wso2

I am working on getting a [WSO2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSO2) server up for a project for work.

I am installing on [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 7. I get:

```
./wso2server.sh
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/jdk1.8.0_144/
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/wso2das-3.1.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx2048m
Loading spark environment variables
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file
/opt/wso2das-3.1.0/lib/endorsed/._geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.0.jar
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It was just one of those Dumb Things ...

I downloaded the server yesterday via Safari on my Mac ... and it unpacked the .zip file automatically.

I don't know .zip subcommands as well as I know tar, so I repacked with tar and gzipped the result for upload to the server I was using.

I must have done something wrong and/or the Mac version of tar is different from the Linux version. Because the .zip file download and upload works perfectly ...

I'll certainly have to watch for this in the future ...